# mvc dropdown list with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have searchable dropdown list [like this link](http://codepen.io/Rio517/pen/NPLbpP).

I am using  ASP.NET MVC

```
<td class="input">
    <select id="classLessonSelect">
        @foreach (Student student in Model) {
            <option value=@student.id>@student.Name @student.Surname</option>
        }
     </select>
</td>
```

I couldn't do it, how can I integrate this to my code?

Comment: you need a fiddle for this kind of question

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a plugin like Select2 https://select2.github.io/.  It has lots of options one of which is a searchable select.  Setting up is easy enough e.g.

$("#selectId").select2();

Answer (score 0):

I used [SumoSelect](http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/sumoselect_demo.html) when I needed searchable dropdown with multiselect option.

For this, I bound data to drop down dynamically, using `jQuery.Ajax` call.

**Disclaimer:** it will require lot of work for getting selected value and such thing because this is based on `HTML` and `JavaScript`, so can't be accessed in code behind like traditional `ASP.Net`'s dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

**First**
You missing some of the details on your `tags` one being the class `selectpicker` of your `<select></select>`

It should rather be like the below:

```
<td class="input">
    <select id="classLessonSelect" class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
        @foreach (var student in Model) {
            <option value=@student.id data-subtext="someSubText">@student.Name @student.Surname</option>
        }
     </select>
</td>
```

**Second**

You need to find out if this plugin already exists in the `BootStrap` in your project if not according to the link you posted you need this http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/